# Which structure to use at server for javascript object array?

Tags: c#, javascript, json, webmethod

I have this object array in javascript, it contains the data from a grid. I want to pass this data to a `webmethod` on the server end, for validation purposes. This is what my array looks like:

```
gridData
[
   Array[6]
   0: Array[0]
      colName: "SSN"
      colValue: "asd"
      isValid: true
      length: 0
      __proto__: Array[0]
   1: Array[0]
      colName: "Birth_Date"
      colValue: "01/03/2013"
      isValid: true
      ........
      ....
]
```

`Array[6]`, represent the data in a particular row for 6 columns in the grid, each index of this array contains data from the cell in the grid.

I want to use an ajax call to server webmethod to validate the data on the server now. Which data structure would be perfect in this regard? Such that it brings a more generic and "least parsing" approach in the application, for the `JSON` data.

Comment: Are you using WebForms, MVC or WebApi?